# Minesweeper probablility question - no mines in one line

Tags: probability

I am struggling with one problem, how to calculate probability that in expert minesweeper (30x16, 99 mines) there will be at least one vertical line containing no mines? The problem is equivalent to: 
Choose 99 unique numbers, between 1 and 480. What's the probability there is such `n` `0 <= n < 30` that every chosen number mod 30 is not `n` ?

Comment: Each class $\pmod {30}$ has exactly $16$ representatives in $[1,480]$.  Thus the probability that you miss a specified class is $\binom {464}{99}/\binom {480}{99}\approx 0.023229$.  Now you could multiply this by $30$ but then you double count the cases where you miss two classes, and triple count those cases where you miss three.  So use the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion!

For any given vertical line, you can calculate the probability that it has no mines.  That is ${450\choose 99} / {480 \choose 99}$  There are 30 of those.

However adding them up is an over-count.  Suppose that there are 2 vertical lines empty.  Then you've counted this case twice.  So you have to subtract off ${16 \choose 2} * {420 \choose 99} / {480 \choose 99}$.

But now suppose you had 3 empty lines?  Well you added it in 3 times in the first step, subtracted it out 3 times in the second, and need to add it in again.  Do you see the pattern?

The answer works out to be:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{16}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}{16 \choose i}{480 - 30i\choose 99}}{480\choose99}
$$
(The last few terms are 0.)